# AMP FORM Error: Response must contain the AMP-Access-Control-Allow-Source-Origin header​

Tags: http-headers, amp-html

> Response must contain the AMP-Access-Control-Allow-Source-Origin
>   header Form submission failed: Error: Response must contain the
>   AMP-Access-Control-Allow-Source-Origin header

**my from**

```
<form id="aa" name="aa" method="post" target="_top" action-xhr="/gonder.asp" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div class="ampstart-input inline-block relative m0 p0 mb3">
<input class="block border-none p0 m0" type="text" name="adSoyad" placeholder="Ad Soyad" required> 
<input class="block border-none p0 m0 telefonKontrol" type="tel" name="telefon" maxlength="10" placeholder="5XX1112233" pattern="[1-9]{1}[0-9]{9}" required>
</div>
<input value="GÖNDER" class="ampstart-btn caps user-valid valid" type="submit">
<div submit-success>
<template type="amp-mustache">
<p>Bilgileriniz bize ulaştı. Size en kısa sürede geri dönüş yapılacaktır.</p>
</template>
</div>
</form>
```

this c# code

```
public virtual ActionResult AmpRedirect(string redirectUrl, string __amp_source_origin)
{
    if (redirectUrl != string.Empty)
    {   
        HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("AMP-Redirect-To", redirectUrl);
        HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("AMP-Access-Control-Allow-Source-Origin", __amp_source_origin);
        HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "AMP-Redirect-To, AMP-Access-Control-Allow-Source-Origin");
    }

    HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("Content-type", "text/json");
    return Json(new {Content = ""});
}
```

I needed a code to work with classic asp

Answer (score 2):

Check this [CORS Security in AMP](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/spec/amp-cors-requests.md#cors-security-in-amp) github guide:

> **CORS Security in AMP**
>
> The AMP CORS security protocol consists of three components:
>
> The CORS Origin header The AMP-Same-Origin custom header Source origin
>   restrictions via __amp_source_origin Ensuring secure requests
>
> **Verify the CORS Origin header**
>
> CORS endpoints receive the requesting origin via the Origin HTTP
>   header. Endpoints should restrict requests to allow only the following
>   origins:
>
> Google AMP Cache subdomain: https://.cdn.ampproject.org (for example,
>   https://nytimes-com.cdn.ampproject.org) Google AMP Cache (legacy):
>   https://cdn.ampproject.org Cloudflare AMP Cache: https://.amp.cloudflare.com The Publisher’s own origins